# How to add zero to integer variable in mysql

Tags: mysql

Please I have a variable @Mont and I want to add zero in the beginning (in a procedure).

I have tried `LPAD` but is not working
like:

```
Mont=1 change to =01
Mont=2 change to =02 
.
.
Mont=11 change to =11
```

I have tried:

```
set Mont=  LPAD(Mont,2,0) ;
```

Comment: `set @Mont = lpad(@Mont, 2, 0);` works fine: http://rextester.com/ZKZ55228

Comment: Thanks , 
i solved my problem.
the problem was not in LPAD